# How to deal with null values using TO_DATE function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create DATETIME by parts but in some cases these parts are null.

**Example**

```
SELECT TO_DATE(STARTDATEMONTH||'-01-'||STARTDATEYEAR, 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) AS BEGIN_DATE FROM V_MYCC_CNPHISTORY_03
```

When the STARTDATEMONTH column is null,

> get the not a valid month

error

When the STARTDATEYEAR column is null, i get the:

> input value not long enough for date format

error

In the cases the values are null, i would like to set a default value. Is that possible or is there some workaround?

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use coalesce:

```
select TO_DATE(coalesce(STARTDATEMONTH,'01')||'-01-'||coalesce(STARTDATEYEAR, '2019'), 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) AS BEGIN_DATE
from Mytable
```

Coalesce and nvl are similar, but coalesce is both ansi friendly, and terminates when it finds a value. Note, the values must be the same data type, eg:

```
coalesce(stringvalue1, stringvalue2)
```

Comment: I believe there's a closing parens missing in your statement - instead of `coalesce(STARTDATEYEAR, '2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY' )`, it should be `coalesce(STARTDATEYEAR, '2019'), 'MM-DD-YYYY' )`

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(COALESCE(STARTDATEMONTH, '01') || '-01-' || COALESCE(STARTDATEYEAR, '2000')), 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) AS BEGIN_DATE
FROM V_MYCC_CNPHISTORY_03
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

> SELECT TO_DATE(coalesce(STARTDATEMONTH,'01') ||'-01-'||
>   coalesce(STARTDATEYEAR,'1700'), 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) AS BEGIN_DATE FROM
>   V_MYCC_CNPHISTORY_03

Comment: Not an oracle funtion

Comment: Correct Jonh. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
SELECT TO_DATE(NVL(STARTDATEMONTH,'01')||'-01-'||NVL(STARTDATEYEAR,'2019'), 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) AS BEGIN_DATE 
FROM V_MYCC_CNPHISTORY_03
```